# Añadir input al final del formulario si escojo un determinado option de un select

Tags: php, html, jquery

tengo esto:

```
$(function () {
        $('#formulario').submit(function() {
            if($('#idGen').val() == "otro") {
                return false;
                $('#formulario').append('<input type="text" id="idGen2" name="idGen2"/>');
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
```

Mi idea es que teniendo un desplegable, si selecciono la opción "Otros", no me deje mandar el formulario y aparezca un nuevo input al final del formulario que me deje escribir un nuevo género para insertarlo. Estoy empezando en JQuery y no me entero.

```
<form id="formulario" action="/misseries/index.php" method="get">
   <select id="idGen" name="idGen">
        {% for gen in data %}
            <option value="{{ gen.idGen }}">{{ gen.genero }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        <option value="otro">Otro...</option>
   </select>
   <button type="submit">Añadir serie</button>
</form>
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formulario" action="/misseries/index.php" method="get">
        <select id="idGen" name="idGen">
             {% for gen in data %}
                 <option value="{{ gen.idGen }}">{{ gen.genero }}</option>
             {% endfor %}
             <option value="otro">Otro...</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="othergender" id="othergender" style="display: none;">
        <button type="submit">Añadir serie</button>
     </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#idGen').on('change',() => {
                $('#othergender').val('')
                if($('#idGen').val() == 'otro'){
                    $('#othergender').css({'display' : 'block'})
                }else{
                    $('#othergender').css({'display' : 'none'})
                }
            })

            $('#formulario').submit((event)=>{
                if($('#idGen').val() == 'otro' && !$('#othergender').val()){
                    event.preventDefault()
                    // HAZ ALGO
                    alert("DEBES ESPECIFICAR EL GENERO PARA ENVIAR EL FORMULARIO.")
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tendremos un `input` para el genero y modificaremos su visibilidad mediante estilos dependiendo de la selección actual del `select`.

Para controlar el envió del formulario y que el `input` posea algún texto, revisamos la selección actual y luego validaremos.